# Free space on disk is not available

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel

I used parted to extend my disk as I would do normally and it appeared successful showing the new 140GB disk.

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi) Disk /dev/sda: 140GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: msdos Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary  xfs          boot  2      1075MB  140GB   139GB   primary               lvm

(parted)
```

When I run pvresize it says that it was was successful and pvdisplay shows:

```
# pvdisplay                                                     --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               rhel
  PV Size               <129.00 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              33023
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          33023
  PV UUID               Rqtlv3-Hjdi-0DR6-I0Qs-gysl-SBSL-HdoW7s
```

So I see that the physical volume did extend it size. I run lvextend then check the logical volume it shows:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                HeW74s-F3v8-ca4a-qZlN-12vO-ID2L-tpQCZk
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-04-09 12:07:26 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                <3.88 GiB
  Current LE             992
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                03H6z4-RMWH-RYRV-5v9T-i8Vl-SVPG-z5CaU7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-04-09 12:07:27 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <25.12 GiB
  Current LE             6430
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                QlDfBH-tFRS-sIPk-d169-mTRV-FgXe-LkCdBC
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-04-09 12:07:27 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                100.00 GiB
  Current LE             25601
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
```

And I run vgdisplay to confirm:

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rhel
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  21
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <129.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              33023
  Alloc PE / Size       33023 / <129.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               XmxEl2-K8LQ-3095-V2Z1-quSv-vDx4-QXonOU
```

All of the sizes show 129.00GB why is it when I run df -h I receive:

```
# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1.9G  8.9M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   50G   45G  5.5G  90% /
/dev/sda1             1014M  191M  824M  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-home   26G  7.2G   18G  29% /home
tmpfs                  379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs                  379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/0
```

I ran the lvextend to extend rhel/root it still showing the 50G. I also noticed that none of the free space can actually be used. I have done nothing different than how I normally would extend a disk and increase space on the lv. I have reattempted this with the same result. I cannot blow away the disk because there are files living here. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Hi, this question has nothing to do with programming and is unfortunately as such off-topic here.  You may want to ask over [unix.se] **or** [su].

Comment: If you're using RHEL 7/8 the default file-system is xfs, btw, not ext4, so it's no surprise that you get an error trying to run `resize2fs`.

Comment: Thank you tink that didn't cross my mind, i was so busy looking elsewhere. xfs_growfs solved my issue!

Comment: Pleased to hear that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need resize FS. For ext do:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

For xfs

```
xfs_growfs /
```

or

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

After extending partition

Comment: # resize2fs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/rhel-root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

This is what I get when i try that.

Comment: @Jthello  resize2fs is for ext